# Split string within list into words in Python

Tags: python, string, split

I'm a newbie in Python, and I need to write a code in Python that will read a text file, then split each words in it, sort it and print it out.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
words = list()


for line in fh:    

    line = line.strip()
    line.split()   
    lst.append(line)

lst.sort()
print lst
```

That's my output -

> ['Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon', 'But soft what light through yonder window breaks', 'It is the east and Juliet is the sun', 'Who is already sick and pale with grienter code herew',
>   'with', 'yonder']

However, when I try to split `lst.split()` it saying

> List object has no attribute split

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You should `extend` the new list with the *splitted* line, rather than attempt to split the strings after appending:

```
for line in fh:    
    line = line.strip()
    lst.extend(line.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) does not magically mutate the string that is split into a `list`. You have to do sth with the return value.

```
for line in fh:    
    # line.split()  # expression has has no effect
    line = line.split()  # statement does
    # lst += line  # shortcut for loop underneath
    for token in line:
        lst = lst + [token]
        lst += [token]
```

The above is a solution that uses a nested loop and avoids `append` and `extend`. The whole line by line splitting and sorting can be done very concisely, however, with a nested generator expression:

```
print sorted(word for line in fh for word in line.strip().split())
```

Comment: The thing is that I we haven't covered extend() function yet, so I think  I am not eligible to use it. I have a read a comment of my instructor that we need to use nested loop in this probelm...

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname, "r")
lines = list()
words = list()
for line in fh:    
    # get an array of words for this line
    words = line.split()
    for w in words: 
       lines.append(w)

lines.sort()
print lines
```

To avoid dups:

```
no_dups_list = list()
for w in lines:
   if w not in no_dups_list:
       no_dups_list.append(w)
```

Comment: we haven't covere join() yet. All we can and need to use here is sort() and append(), it's mandatory

Comment: Edited to use only sort and append ;) Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however, I still get wrong result. I have -

['Arise and envious fair kill moon sun the ', 'But breaks light soft through what window yonder ', 'It Juliet and east is is sun the the ', 'Who already and grief is pale sick with ']

instead of - 

['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']

Comment: Ok I misunderstood what you asked. Now it should work as you expect.

Comment: thanks, now it works as it should. Just one more question - how to make it to avoid repeated words in a list?

Comment: You should use set, but I think you've not covered them yet.
You can iterate over a copy of the list. I edit the answer....

Comment: I've read that we can use if statement for checking, however I don't know where and how use it

Comment: It works perfect! Now I will spend rest of my day to figure out how does it word)) Thank you!!